# Whats the easier/elegant option when it comes to porting Classic ASP websites to newer technology/platform?

Tags: rest, asp-classic, migrating

we have a number of classic asp based websites with CMS functionality. Most run on Mysql 4.1
Please correct or suggest me better options. 
My plan is to standardize the existing code to use RESTful methods where ever possible.
The Business logic code can now be replaced in phased manner with ASP.NET codebase.
I haven't yet looked at Razor view engine. How relevant would that be for to adopt in this scenario?

I have fairly good experience tackling the database port to MS SQL Server. So I'm not much worried on that side.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, nothing is easier or more elegant than well written classic ASP.

If it ain't broken - don't fix it.